# Highlighted anchor in nav menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, anchor

I have a WordPress system. The problem is my nav menu.
I have a link to a subsite in my menu and an anchor point to a part of the main site.
So if I link the anchor like this: `#test` it works on the main site. If I want to click this on the subsite it doesn't work.

If I link the anchor like this: `http://localhost/#test` it works on the sub site.

But on the main page the anchor is highlighted. I know that it's because it's a current-menu-item, but I don't want it highlighted. I could style the class current-menu-item like the normal color.

But I want that the active link is highlighted.

My thoughts of the answer was that maybe I link it like this: `#test` and then I redirect the link to this: `http://localhost/#test`

But it would be nice if there is another solution.
I could not find something about this topic in the www. If anyone has a nice documentation it would be nice.

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Remove the hash "#" tag and try.

Comment: the # is the anchor point. If I don't use it, it's a link to a site that is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution. I add some JS to remove the CSS class that add the highlight effect.

So this is working perfect. It was at the start a little bit difficult because I can't select the menu-item with `getElementsByClassName`. But with the querySelector it works fine.

The JS code looks like this:
For the first anchor:

```
document.querySelector("#menu-navigation-de-1 > li.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.current-menu-item.current_page_item.menu-item-home.menu-item-49874.nav-item").classList.remove("current-menu-item");
```

For the second anchor:

```
document.querySelector("#menu-navigation-de-1 > li.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.current-menu-item.current_page_item.menu-item-home.menu-item-300.nav-item").classList.remove("current-menu-item");
```

Thank you @ibes that you helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use it like this:
`#test` 
It refers to a anchor on the currently visited site.

So for the main site it will be
yourwebsite.tld/#test

On the subsite it will be
yourwebsite.tld/subside/#test

Very different things.

Use the full link so that the menu always points to the same fraction of information.

If you don't want the full link to be highlighted you will likely need to use JavaScript.

You can eg. add a class to all menu links with anchor tag - and take away the highlight effect.
Or you could compare every menu link with the current url in the url bar - if this is not a perfect match - add a class / or add a class if it is a perfect match.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I already thought something like this. I have problems with JS, so if you have a little help for me to start it would be nice.

Comment: Than the first question is, which root do you want to go?

I imagine the cleanest could be to put a class on the menu link that has an exact match with the current url.  
Than I would suggest to extend the current CSS rule that highlights the current active tab in a way that leaves everything as it is, if no JS is executed and just reduces the highlighting if JS is not active - sounds good?

Do you work with plain JS or jQuery?

Comment: What you need is:

- after the pages is finished loading the DOM (document ready)  

- get all links in that specific menu (get elements by selector)  

- get the current url in the adress bar (something like window.location)  

- for every link, compare the href attribute with the current url  

- if there is a match, add a class to it  


As your page refreshes every time someone navigates your site you just need to execute this once on page load and don't need to change things later on

(sorry - I cant do line breaks?!)